# Which Unixes support cross-device filesystem links (in particular for rename)?

Tags: files, rename, devices, system-calls, architecture

Just read the following on the FreeBSD [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/2/rename/) for the rename syscall:

```
...
[EXDEV] The link named by to and the file named by from are on
        different logical devices (file systems).  Note that
        this error code will not be returned if the implemen-
        tation permits cross-device links.
...
```

Especially:

> .. **if the implementation permits cross-device links.**

Are there Unixes that implement this behavior using cross-device links? Which ones?

Sidenote:

One case, where it would be useful to have cross-device links is atomic renames. How can one have atomic renames if a the system (like most) does not support these over devices?

Comment: Many `mv` implementations will fail over to `cp` and `rm` if things are on different filesystems (I'd say most do it now).  Are you asking which do that?  Or are you asking which do cross-device links?

Comment: @kurtm, Yes I mainly wanted to know, which systems have support for this. Added a short note to my question, regarding a use case.

Comment: @kurtm the question is about kernel syscall rather than  userspace `mv`.

Comment: In the end, I'd love to know, how to do an atomic move or rename cross-device (if src and dst are on the same device, it's trivial).